# how to get full size in cricleimageview?

Tags: java, android, xml, size

when i put image in cricleimageview from the server it cropped i need the full size for this image i tried all things i think but still the same problem i used center crop

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/doctorDetailsImg"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/green"
    android:src="@drawable/mahmoud" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`centerCrop` crops the image to fit the bounds. And further, I don't think the library allows other scale types.

Comment: yes error when i use another scale type , do u have any method to make image full size in image with round shape

Comment: The library doesn't allow it. You can download the source code of the library n try modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` may cause crash You should need to set image of specific size to set full image in CircleImageview